# how to use Numpy to fit a function and get area under curve

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have a list of values, which can be considered Y axis. The X axis is the index of the element in the list.

for example

Y=
403
486
585
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6
642.6

if I plot these data it will look like this :

[image: Curve Plot]

I would like to find a way  to get the function in first order polynomial for this line and the area under the curve.

Comment: do you want a single function or two functions for that graph? Anyway, you would need to specify the function order

Comment: I need one function for it. Also in the first order. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `polyfit` to find the function and `trapz` to calculate the area with trapezoidal rule.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Y = [403, 486, 585, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6, 642.6]
X = range(len(Y))
Z = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
A = np.trapz(Y,x=X)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(X,Y)
plt.hold()
ax.plot(X,Z[1] + np.multiply(Z[0],X))
```

[image: curve and fitcurve]